# Why won't geolocation work on CodePen?

Tags: javascript, codepen

I'm trying to create a weather app for Free Code Camp and when I load everything on a localhost it works fine.  Whenever I try to run it on Codepen however it doesn't work.

Here's the link to my Codepen: http://codepen.io/GeorgeMort/pen/LWpXPZ

Here's my JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
  temperature = document.getElementById("temperature");
  loc = document.getElementById("location");
  icon = document.getElementById("icon");

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    var showPosition = function(position) {
      updateByGeo(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    };
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
   var zip = window.prompt("Unable to find your location.  What is your zip code?");
  updateByZip(zip);
  }
};
```

--AND--

```
function updateByGeo(lat, lon) {
  var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?" + "lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&APPID=" + APPID;

  sendRequest(url);
}
```

I've tried to use CodePen on both Chrome and Safari.  I've run into more issues using Chrome for this project so really could just use some help in getting it to work on Safari.

I really appreciate the help.  Thanks!

Comment: Guess you didn't look in your console ~ *"`getCurrentPosition()` and `watchPosition()` no longer work on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS."*

Answer (score 1):

Try the same link, but with HTTPS...!

https://codepen.io/GeorgeMort/pen/LWpXPZ

This API only works on secure sites.

```
//And some code, appaz
```

Comment: The code is because SO insisted I added some with a CodePen link.

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding something.  The link you provided with HTTPS still doesn't come up either.  I tried changing any link I had within my code from HTTP to HTTPS as well and I still get nothing for geolocation.

Comment: Ah, it works for me in the sense that it asks for my location. Is yours not asking? If so, you may have already declined in your browser settings.

Comment: I went to my Chrome location settings and Codepen is allowed to access my location.  When I use Chrome or Safari now on a localHost the geolocation works only not on Codepen.